# Copy files with elevated credentials in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Searched and searched, but cannot find an answer that works specifically for what I am looking for.

I want to call a PowerShell script from a logon vbscript that runs on logon. The PowerShell script will copy a file from a server network share to C:\Windows, but I need to embed credentials securely in the PowerShell script because the script will be hosted on a common share. I have already generated the AES key file and the password file I am decrypting with the AES key.

This is what I have so far

```
$User = "itadmin"
$source = "\\server\cip$\misc-programs\new_inb_install\inb.exe"
$destination = "C:\Windows\"
$PasswordFile = "\\server\cip$\misc-programs\new_inb_install\psw.txt"
$KeyFile = "\\server\cip$\misc-programs\new_inb_install\AES.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ` 
-ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key)

Copy-Item $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Credential $MyCredential
```

The error I get when I run the code is

```
>     Copy-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive
> cmdlet. Perform the operation again without 
>     specifying credentials.
>     At line:12 char:1
>     + Copy-Item $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Credential $MyC ...
>     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I should also mention, the credentials I am specifying I don't need for access to the server. I need to use those credentials to deal with UAC and make sure the end user isn't prompted for the service account creds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass (or if you like, "programmatically accept") the UAC prompt, the answer is "no." If it were possible, it's exactly what all malware would do.

Comment: Do you have the Active Directory installed?

Comment: Yes, AD is in our environment.

Comment: Read this first: [FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2007/06/29/faq-why-cant-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/).